# how do I override the default bounds (max and min) for my payload in ur_driver (and/or ur_modern_driver)?

Tags: ros, universal-robots, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm very very new to [ur_driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot) (urd, for short) and [ur_modern_driver](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver) (urMd, for short) and I really do not understand how they work.  I thought urMd was advertised as a drop in replacement for urd, but when I try to build my workspace with only urMD without urd there, it fails.  So apparently there are some dependencies or assumptions there that I don't understand.

So I've got both cloned from github and built on Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic.  And I'm able to control my UR10 arm using the sample test_move.py script, which is completely awesome!  But I am needing to pick up a 16kg payload, so I'm calling the SetPayload service (which appears to be in urd, not urMd) and it won't let me change the value above 9.9999

So where is the limit of 10kg set and how do I go about changing that limit?  I saw a reference in the urMd code to the parameter server so I changed the value on the parameter server, but for some reason I am still unable to set the value using the service above 9.9999

So I'm not sure where that value is actually being limited.

Thanks for any help you can give.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269049/how-do-i-override-the-default-bounds-(max-and-min)-for-my-payload-in-ur_driver-(and/or-ur_modern_driver)?/) by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on ROS Answers with karma: 486 on 2017-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm such an idiot.  Newbie mistake.  It's coded into the launch file that I've been calling.

Sorry to waste your time.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2017-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-17**:
You're probably already aware of this, but 16 Kg is way outside of the specs for a UR10. It's max rated payload is 10 Kg. That is also the reason why the default max value for the `set_payload` service is 10.

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2017-08-17**:
Hmmm.  I was not aware of this 10 kg limitation.  The pendant lets me type in values in the init screen all the way up to 20 kg.  Over that value, it gives me an error.

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2017-08-17**:
Geez.  There it is in the printed specs.  10 kg.  I can't believe we all missed that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-18**:
Sorry you missed that.

With URs it's relatively easy to remember: UR3 -> 3kg, UR5 -> 5kg and UR10 -> 10kg.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-18**:
But perhaps there is a reason it allows you to enter values > 10 kg.

I'd contact UR to ask them to clarify why that is.

Perhaps up to 20 kg is acceptable / ok-ish, but you'll get reduced performance / can't use the entire work envelope.

That's how it works with a lot of (industrial) robots.